# Formal notation for replacing a tuple component

Tags: notation

What are the widely recognised notations to define a function that replaces the n-th element in tuple?

Let suppose that I want to formally define a function $r_3: N^8 \times N \rightarrow N^8$ informally defined as $r_3(t,a)$ is equal to the tuple $t$ with the 3rd element replaced by $a$.

Are all of the following notations widely accepted?
Is there any additional widely accepted notation that I have not listed?

1. $f(t,a) \equiv (t[1],t[2],a,t[4],t[5],t[6],t[7],t[8])$
2. $f(t,a) \equiv (\pi_1(t),\pi_2(t),a,\pi_4(t),\pi_5(t),\pi_6(t),\pi_7(t),\pi_8(t))$
3. $f(t,a) \equiv (t_1, t_2, a, t_4, t_5, t_6, t_7, t_8)\quad \text{if } t=(t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4, t_5, t_6, t_7, t_8) $

Comment: I would say 3 is "widely accepted", and the other two will be OK only if you first specify the notation $t[j]$ or $\pi_j(t)$.

Comment: Any shorter option?

Comment: Are you really talking about "tuples" rather than lists or strings or sequences?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about tuples as in my real use case each element is actually from a different domain. In my example I simplified it and made all of the tuple components be in the $N$ domain.